# Initializing enum class as null

Tags: c++, enums

I am wondering if it is possible to initialize an enum class as null. I have written up a short example to illustrate what I am asking about.

I have a header here that defines an enum class called `ColorOptions`

```
#ifndef COLORS_HPP
#define COLORS_HPP

enum class ColorOptions
{
  RED,
  BLUE
};
#endif
```

and I also have a class that is using this enum class to print colors based on the enum value

```
#include "Colors.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void printColor(ColorOptions col);

int main()
{
  printColor(ColorOptions::RED);
  printColor(ColorOptions::BLUE);
}

void printColor(ColorOptions col)
{
  switch(col)
  {
  case ColorOptions::RED:
    std::cout << "The color is red" << std::endl;
    break;
  case ColorOptions::BLUE:
    std::cout << "The color is blue" << std::endl;
    break;
  default:
    std::cout << "The color is unknown" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to initalize a `ColorOptions` as something other than `RED` or `BLUE` in this case? I want to reach the default case of the `printColor` method, but I am not sure if it is possible without adding another type to the `ColorOptions` enum.

Comment: Why not make an enum value of `NONE`?

Comment: call it COUNT and use it to get the number of enum values + as a dummy value :)

Comment: Either you define an enum value of `NONE` or you use `std::optional` for your `col` function parameter. Which one to choose, depends on what you want to express with the case when the color is "NULL".

Comment: @NathanOliver I am just wondering if there is a way to do this without making another enum value. I know it seems like the obvious solution, but the larger problem I will be applying this question to does not allow me to make any adjustments to the enum I will be using.

Comment: @t.niese if I define `col` in this case as `std::optional<ColorOptions> col`, doesn't that change the datatype of `col` and will no longer allow me to pass `ColorOptions` types to the method?

Comment: @BrentMB it will still allow you to pass a value of the type `ColorOptions` to that function.  As a note: The time it took you to write your comment was most likely longer then it would have taken you to just test it to see if it will work or not ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to get a value not of the valid enumerations is to use `static_cast`. That would look like

```
printColor(static_cast<ColorOptions>(5));
```

and that will output

```
The color is unknown
```

If you can use C++17 then a nice thing you can do would be to change the enum to something like

```
enum class ColorOptions
{
  NONE,
  RED,
  BLUE
};
```

and then you can call your function like

```
printColor({});
```

which will give you an implicit value of `NONE` and cause `The color is unknown` to be print.

Comment: Thank you! The `static_cast<ColorOptions>(5)` is exactly what I was looking for. Adding the `NONE` type to the enum is the cleanest and most logical solution, but the case I am working with does not allow me to change the enum at all.